# Perturbation of linear Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banachspace. And $L: X \to X$ a linear bounded Operator. Given $ \varepsilon > 0$  i want to find $\lambda>0 $  such that $\| \lambda I - L \| \le \varepsilon $. Using the Standard Norm for linear Operators.  Is this possible?

Comment: Shall we explore this with  a simple, finite-dimensional example? For example, if we take $X = \mathbb C^2$, $L = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $\epsilon = \frac 1 3$, then clearly we can't find such a $\lambda$. But maybe I misunderstood your question?

Comment: No you didn't. Thank you. You might post this as an answer if you want to.

Comment: Cool - glad it helped! I've got to go, but free to post an answer yourself! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that to each $ \epsilon >0$ there is $\lambda ( \epsilon)>0$ such that

$||\lambda ( \epsilon)I-L|| \le \epsilon$. Then, for each $n \in  \mathbb N$ there is $\lambda_n >0$ such that

(*) $||\lambda_n I-L|| \le 1/n$.

From $| \lambda_n|=|| \lambda_nI-L+L|| \le || \lambda_nI-L||+ ||L|| \le 1/n+||L|| \le 1+||L||$ we see that $( \lambda_n)$ is bounded. Therefore we can  , without loss of generality, assume that $( \lambda_n)$ converges. Let $\lambda_0$ the limit of this sequence.

Now, from (*) with $ n \to \infty$, we get:

$$L= \lambda_0I.$$

Consequence: an operator $L$ has your above property $ \iff L$ is of the form $\lambda_0I.$

Answer (score 0):

The following generalisation of my answer above might be of some interest. The proof should be clear.

Let $E$ be a normed space over $\mathbb K= \mathbb R$ or $\mathbb K= \mathbb C$. For $x,y \in E$ the follwing assertions are equivalent:

$(1)$ for each $ \epsilon >0$ there is $\lambda \in \mathbb K$ with $|| \lambda x-y|| \le \epsilon$;

$(2)$ $x$and $y$ are linearly dependent.